# How do I get hadoop to ignore \n characters in my input files?

Tags: java, string, hadoop, io, newline

I am writing an inverted index creator using Hadoop's map reduce functions. Some of the lines on my input file have written into them the characters \n as actual characters (not ASCII 10, but rather the two actual characters '\' and 'n'). For some reason I don't understand, this seems to cause the map function to split my lines into two separate lines.

Here are a few sample line from a few of my files.

> 32155: Wyldwood Radio: On the Move WILL begin on Friday May 1st, as originally planned!\n\nWe had some complications with... http://t.co/g8STpuHn5Q
>
> 5: RT @immoumita: #SaveJalSatyagrahi\nJal Satyagraha 'holding on to the truth by water' https://t.co/x3XgRvCE5H via @4nks
>
> 15161: RT @immoumita: #SaveJalSatyagrahi\nJal Satyagraha 'holding on to the truth by water' https://t.co/x3XgRvCE5H via @4nks

Here is the output:

> co    :78516: tweets0001:30679;2, ... , tweets0001:We had some complications with... http;1, ...
>
> x3XgRvCE5H    :2: tweets0000:Jal Satyagraha 'holding on to the truth by water' https;2

And the following is my map reduce:

MAP

```
public static class Map extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text> {
     private final static Text word = new Text();
   private final static Text location = new Text();

     public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, OutputCollector<Text, Text> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {

     String line = value.toString();

     int colon_index = line.indexOf(":");
     if(colon_index > 0)
     {
       String tweet_num = line.substring(0,colon_index);
       line = line.substring(colon_index + 1);

       StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line," !@$%^&*()-+=\"\\:;/?><.,{}[]|`~");
       FileSplit fileSplit = (FileSplit)reporter.getInputSplit();
       String filename = fileSplit.getPath().getName();
       location.set(filename + ":" + tweet_num);
       while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
         word.set(tokenizer.nextToken());
         output.collect(word, location);
       }
     }
}
```

REDUCE

```
public static class Reduce extends MapReduceBase implements Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text> {
     public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<Text> values, OutputCollector<Text, Text> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
       boolean first = true;
     int count = 0;
     StringBuilder locations = new StringBuilder();
     HashMap<String,Integer> frequencies = new HashMap<String, Integer>();


       while (values.hasNext()) {
        String location = values.next().toString();
        if(frequencies.containsKey(location)){
          int frequency = frequencies.get(location).intValue() + 1;
          frequencies.put(location,new Integer(frequency));
        }
        else{
          frequencies.put(location,new Integer(1));
        }
        count++;
       }
     for(String location : frequencies.keySet()){
       int frequency = frequencies.get(location).intValue();
       if(!first)
        locations.append(", ");
       locations.append(location);
       locations.append(";"+frequency);
       first = false;
     }
     StringBuilder finalString = new StringBuilder();
     finalString.append(":"+String.valueOf(count)+": ");
     finalString.append(locations.toString());
       output.collect(key, new Text(finalString.toString()));
     }
   }
```

The general data flow is to map each line to a {Word,filename:line_number} pair, then reduce these pairs by counting how often it shows up. The output should be:

Word-->:occurences: filename1:line_number:occurences_on_this_line, filename2....

The map reduce part works just fine, and you can even see from my example that the tweet on line 5 and 15161 both contain the string `x3XgRvCE5H`, and, since my Mapper looks for a colon before appending a line number and these two tweets contain the same text, they both map to the same index location, giving a "frequency" value of 2.

So, my question is: how do I get Hadoop's input format to not read the characters "\n" as a newline? After all, they are NOT ASCII 10, the actual new line, line feed character, but instead two separate characters.

Answer (score 1):

You have to extend `FileInputFormat` and write a new class to override the behaviour. For example:

```
public class ClientTrafficInputFormat extends FileInputFormat {

    @Override
    public RecordReader createRecordReader(InputSplit split, TaskAttemptContext context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        return new ClientTrafficRecordReader();
    }

}
```

also RecordReader should be overwritten

```
public class ClientTrafficRecordReader extends
        RecordReader<ClientTrafficKeyWritable, ClientTrafficValueWritable> {

    ...

    private LineRecordReader reader = new LineRecordReader(); // create your own RecordReader this is where you have to mention not to use '\n' but it should be read as "\"and "n"

    @Override
    public void initialize(InputSplit is, TaskAttemptContext tac) throws IOException,
            InterruptedException {

        reader.initialize(is, tac);

    }
     ...
    @Override
public boolean nextKeyValue() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
      //customize your input 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use spark to replace all newline,carriage return and combination of both with NULL. like below -

// read file in RDD

scala> val readRDD = sc.wholeTextFiles("hdfs://hanamenode/input_dir/file_name.txt")
readRDD: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, String)] = hdfs://hanamenode/input_dir/file_name.txt  MapPartitionsRDD[10] at wholeTextFiles at :24

// tranform and replace all newline feeds, where "\u0007" BELL is delimiter on my file, you can use delimiter as per your files

scala> val tranformRDD = readRDD.map(x => x._2.replaceAll("\\(\n|\r|\r\n)", "\\ ").split("\u0007").mkString("\u0007"))
tranformRDD: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = MapPartitionsRDD[15] at map at :25

//write to the target location

scala> tranformRDD.saveAsTextFile("hdfs:haname/output_dir")